# Windows phone 8.1 notification on new image and contact added

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a windows phone 8.1 application which backs up all the media (photos, videos, music), contacts to a server.

Is there a notification mechanism that exists on windows phone 8.1 in a scenario where the user clicks a photo and the application can get a notification that there is a new image pending to be uploaded to the server?

Same thing with contacts as well, is there a notification mechanism of this sort?

Currently what I do is calculate a checksum for each file to see if they are on the server or not. But it's a costly process.

Answer (score 0):

Currently windows phone 8.1 does not provide any mechanism for 3rd party apps to know that a new image or contact has been added(so no notification exists). You have to stick with checking it by your app every time you want to sync the data.

But instead of calculating checksum why not store image updatedon datetime of the uploaded image in phone local storage and every time check if the image is updated on the server or not? and if it is not updated on the server than upload the image below is the code on how to get Image Last Modified date.

```
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
            var filePropreties = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            var fileLastModeifiedDate = filePropreties.DateModified;
```

Hope it helps!